# Return session data from external microservice to Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests, django-sessions

I am trying to link an external python script which is kind of like a function webscraping the other domain with the user login data sent from the django views. After the external script is sucessfully ran, the result data will be return back to the django views and show in the page.

So far I can sucessfully done the above but as the external python script consist of a part of logging in an external domain and scrape the data. I want the logged-in session from the external script to be returned back to the django then the user can access the data from my page without needing to log in again.

Here is my code

This is my external python script which consist of using the Requests library

```
def webscrape (email, pwd, dj_req):

    # use the data from django views to login the other domain and webscrape
    URL = 'www.login.com'
    payload = {
        'name': email,
        'pwd': pwd,
    }
    s = dj_req.session() 
    #Trying to utilize the user's request data
    r1 = s.post(URL, data=payload)
    list1 = r1.text

    return list1,s
    #Return the logged-in session to django views
```

This is my django view

```
 from ... import webscrape 
    
    def inputdata(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formdata = userform(request.POST)
        if formdata.is_valid():

            email=formdata.cleaned_data['email']
            pwd=formdata.cleaned_data['password']


            list1,logedin_session = webscrape(email,pwd,request) 
            #Inject the user request to the external script
            request.session = logedin_session
            #Try to overwrite the user's request by the session from the external script
            return AnotherDjangoViews(request,list1)
            

    else:
        email=''
        password=''
        formdata = userform(initial={'email':email,'password':password,})
    

    return render(request, 'xxx.html', {'form': userform})
```

This code return error of "'SessionStore' object is not callable".
I know i am on the wrong path but i cannot find any resources on how to interact with django's session and requests' session. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After some research on similar thread in the internet, it seems impossible or difficult to achieve what I wish to complete.
Since in the security perspective, it seems strange that when a client access your website and you can obtain the session id of the client accessing another external domain.